# Distinct Select in SQL and Order by

Tags: sql

I wrote a query in sql, where I will keep just one time the Companies.ID, that is why I use Distinct.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Companies.ID, Companies.Company, Abo.Ende 
FROM Companies
LEFT JOIN Abo on Companies.ID = Abo.CompanyID 
ORDER BY Abo.Ende
```

The table Abo.Ende has more entries for the Abo.CompanyID and I would like to get as result the distinct Companies.ID with the most recent Abo.Ende. Note: Abo.Ende is a datetime field and I would like to get the newest.

I am wondering if this is the best way to do that. Is there another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `group by`, not `distinct`:

```
SELECT Companies.ID, Companies.Company, max(Abo.Ende)
FROM Companies
LEFT JOIN Abo on Companies.ID = Abo.CompanyID 
GROUP BY Companies.ID, Companies.Company
```

A comment on your `DISTINCT` usage:

`DISTINCT` operates on the *whole* row. So it will return distinct combinations of all column values in a single row. If you include a PK column (Probably `companies.id` in your case), distinct would not "remove" any rows as the PK is unique by definition and if one column is unique across all rows, then all the columns of the result are "unique" (in the sense of the `DISTINCT` operator) as well.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I was wondering if I could use only GROUP By Companies.Company, because it gives me an error.

Comment: @DimitraMicha: you have to list all non-aggregated columns in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thank you a lot, also for the comment. I must have misunderstood the usage of Distinct.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT Companies.ID, 
       Companies.Company, 
       MAX(Abo.Ende) AS Ende
FROM Companies
LEFT JOIN Abo on Companies.ID = Abo.CompanyID
GROUP BY Companies.ID, 
       Companies.Company
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Companies.ID, Companies.Company, max(Abo.Ende)
FROM Companies
LEFT JOIN Abo on Companies.ID = Abo.CompanyID 
GROUP BY Companies.ID, Companies.Company
```